# Sequential scan in postgres is taking surprisingly long. How do I determine the hardware bottleneck?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, io

I have a vanilla postgres database running on a small server with only one table called "posts". 
The table is on the order of ~5GB and contains 9 million rows.

When I run a simple sequential scan opertaion it takes about **51 seconds!**:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE select count(*) from posts;
                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=988701.41..988701.42 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=51429.607..51429.607 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on posts  (cost=0.00..966425.33 rows=8910433 width=0) (actual time=0.004..49530.025 rows=9333639 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 51429.639 ms
(3 rows)
```

- The server specs:

  - Xeon E3-1220v2
  - 4GB RAM
  - 500GB hard drive (stock 7200rpm, No RAID)
  - postgres 9.1
  - Ubuntu 12.04
  - No L1 or L2 cache
  - Postgres runs on 1 of 4 cores
  - Postgres configuration is standard, nothing special
  - I have isolated the server, and nothing else significant is running on the server

When the query runs, the disk is getting read at a rate of ~122M/s (according to iotop) and a "IO>" of ~90%. Only 1 core is getting used at 12% capacity of it's capacity. It looks like little to no memory is used in this operation, maybe ~5MB.

From these statistics is sounds like the bottleneck is IO, but I'm confused because the disk is capable of reading way faster, (from a speed test I did using `sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda` I was getting about 10,000M/s) but at the same time `iotop` is showing a value of 90% which I'm not fully understanding.

Comment: `SELECT pg_relation_size('mytable'), pg_total_relation_size('mytable'), version()`. But really, a cheapo 7200rpm spinning rust? Your server is extremely bottlenecked on I/O. Get a decent disk, or put in 12GB or more of RAM so you can easily cache the whole table.in RAM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your disk certainly does not read at 10GB/sec :) This is cached performance. The hardware is maxed out here. 120MB/sec is a typical sequential rate.

I see no indication of a hardware problem. The hardware is being used maximally efficiently.

```
51sec * 120MB/sec ~ 6GB
```

You say the table is 5GB in size. Probably it is more like 6GB.

The numbers make sense. No problem here.

Comment: seems spot on. What you *can* do though is run multiple queries and each sequential scan should "ride on the tails" of the one in front. Clever, eh?

Comment: You are 100% correct that the 10GB per second is cached performance - my bad.
I know you say 120Mb/s is normal, but how do I determine the read rate that my HD *should* be operating at? And how do I speed this up?

Comment: Actually testing buffered read, it turns out that this is inline with expectations:
 Timing buffered disk reads: 378 MB in  3.00 seconds = 125.86 MB/sec
What hardware can I use to speed this up? SSDs and RAID I guess?

Comment: RAM. Put everything into memory. If that's too expensive consider SSDs. Expect 500MB/s per drive. But have you exhausted all query tuning opportunities yet? Maybe no need for new hardware.